# MySQLI - UPDATE multiple rows with different values in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to understand how to UPDATE multiple rows with different values and I just don't get it.

`cache_id`
  `cache_user_email`
  `cache_number`
  `cache_final_price`

I want to update two fields in different rows recorded with the same email

(Code added from comment to answer)

```
  $sql_update_cache_number = "UPDATE cache 
         SET cache_number='".$_POST['cache_number']."', 
             cache_final_price='".$per_product_price."' 
         WHERE cache_product_id='".$row_add_to_cart['product_id']."' 
              AND cache_user_email='".$_SESSION['email']."'"; 
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update_cache_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should post your code together with your question.

To update a value with (My)SQL you are maybe looking for a statement like `UPDATE your_table SET cache_number=1, cache_final_price=3 WHERE cache_user_email = 'user@isp.com'`

What this does is searching all rows with `cache_user_email = 'user@isp.com'` and updating the values of `cache_number` and `cache_final_price`.

Comment: My code:
          `$sql_update_cache_number = "UPDATE cache SET cache_number='".$_POST['cache_number']."',cache_final_price='".$per_product_price."' WHERE cache_product_id='".$row_add_to_cart['product_id']."' AND cache_user_email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql_update_cache_number);`
Unfortunately, only the first row of the table updates and does not update the rest of the rows

Comment: If not all data is updated, then you `where` doesn't match the other rows. Maybe there is a hidden space or something else. You can test what is being updated by executing a `SELECT` with the exact same `WHERE` as in your `UPDATE`. And look for `Prepared Statements`, your code is totaly insecure and vulnerable for SQL injection.